# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32') in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, valueerror

Here is my code I tried to fix the problem but I couldn't. I always get the same error. ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')
I added these 2 line for change the dtype

```
cols = cancer.select_dtypes(exclude=['float']).columns
cancer[cols] = cancer[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float', errors='coerce')
```

but I still get the same error. How can I fix it?

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer;

cancer = pd.read_csv('breast.csv')
cancer.Class = [1.0 if i == "benign" else 0.0 for i in cancer.Class]
cols = cancer.select_dtypes(exclude=['float']).columns
cancer[cols] = cancer[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float', errors='coerce')
X=cancer.drop('Class', axis = 1)
y=cancer.Class.values

X = (X - np.min(X)) / (np.max(X) - np.min(X))
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train , X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
                                                     y,
                                                     test_size = 0.2,
                                                     random_state = 0)
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier;

tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

[image]

Comment: Please post errors as text, not images, to help people who want to help you search

Comment: Also, this is very hard to diagnose without a [mre]. *At least* post the data.csv, or better, post a minimal version of it, *as copy-pastable code* to allow us to easily help you

Comment: And just an untested assumption - you simply have `nans` in your data. converting the dtype won't help. Try `df[df.isna()] = some_default`

Comment: Tell us about `X_train` - shape, dtype, maximum value, maybe some of the values.